# Facing warning: "Nic is not connected to any gates!" in VEINS simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm using Veins 5.0, OMNet++ 5.5.1, SUMO 1.2.0

I'm getting the following warning in my simulation:

```
WARN (PhyLayer80211p)mpsScenario.node[0].nic.phy80211p: Nic is not connected to any gates!
```

This is how my mpsScenario.ned file looks:

```
import org.car2x.veins.base.connectionManager.ConnectionManager;
import org.car2x.veins.base.modules.BaseWorldUtility;
import org.car2x.veins.modules.mobility.traci.TraCIScenarioManager*;
import org.car2x.veins.modules.obstacle.ObstacleControl;
import org.car2x.veins.modules.world.annotations.AnnotationManager;
import org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car;

import org.car2x.veins.mps.traffic.BaseTrafficManager;


network mpsScenario {
    parameters:
        double playgroundSizeX @unit(m); // x size of the area the nodes are in (in meters)
        double playgroundSizeY @unit(m); // y size of the area the nodes are in (in meters)
        double playgroundSizeZ @unit(m); // z size of the area the nodes are in (in meters)
        string trafficType;
        @display("bgb=$playgroundSizeX,$playgroundSizeY");
        @figure[description](type=text; pos=700,30; font=,,bold; 
                text="Aerolink(TM) Misbehavior Protection System Simulation");
    submodules:
        obstacles: ObstacleControl {
            @display("p=240,50");
        }
        annotations: AnnotationManager {
            @display("p=260,50");
        }
        connectionManager: ConnectionManager {
            parameters:
                @display("p=150,0;i=abstract/multicast");
        }
        world: BaseWorldUtility {
            parameters:
                playgroundSizeX = playgroundSizeX;
                playgroundSizeY = playgroundSizeY;
                playgroundSizeZ = playgroundSizeZ;
                @display("p=30,0;i=misc/globe");
        }
        manager: TraCIScenarioManagerForker {
            parameters:
                @display("p=115,60");
        }
        trafficManager: <trafficType> like BaseTrafficManager {
            @display("p=115,0");
        }
        node[0]: Car {
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
}
```

which is basically the default file with one custom `trafficManager` module. Also, the `manager` points to `TraCIScenarioManagerForker`.

The Car.ned module is same as default that is provided by VEINS 5.0.

Since mostly everything is default, I don't understand why I am getting the aforementioned warning. Due to this warning I am getting a `std::bad_alloc` error as soon as a new BSM is received by a vehicle.

**Edit 1: Add MWE which is in github repo**

My issue can be recreated using the following steps:

1. Clone my branch `v5` from my fork of [veins](https://github.com/sommer/veins):

```sh
git clone --branch v5 https://github.com/raash1d/veins
```

2. Start OMNeT++
3. Run the simulation from `scenarios/mps/omnetpp.ini`; choose "Gui" Config name.
4. Click "RUN" and observe the log messages in OMNeT++ Qtenv window. As soon as a vehicle is created, a warning is generated for the Nic module.

This eventually causes the `std::bad_alloc` error.

Comment: would you be able to share a link to a Github (or similar) project which exhibits this problem? This way, interested parties could try to reproduce your error.

Comment: @ChristophSommer, My apologies for the delay. I created a minimal working example on my github repo (https://github.com/raash1d/veins/tree/v5). If you could please take a look about what the problem is, that would be really great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OMNeT++ simulation playground is configured ([in omnetpp.ini](https://github.com/raash1d/veins/blob/8b6e43966e160c758d15a9f9c83f9e171d3fdad3/scenarios/mps/omnetpp.ini#L33)) to go from (0,0) to (10000,10000).

Your SUMO road network (in .net.xml) goes from 0.00,0.00 to 5527.41,7491.84 (this is okay), but your SUMO buildings (in .poly.xml) go from -3255.66,-3540.81 to 5794.35,8029.21.

[image]

This means that your simulation will try to use buildings that are outside the playground, which crashes it. You will need to increase the size of the simulation playground.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Increasing the simulation playground does solve the issue of `std::bad_alloc` on the reception of BSM. However, I still get the warning that Nic is not connected to any gates. Is it a problem that the SUMO buildings start from -3255.66,-3540.81 to 5794.35,8029.21 whereas the net  goes from 0.00,0.00 to 5527.41,7491.84?